# How to change placeholder content of an input with jQuery.on in Bootstrap framework?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have an input with Bootstrap placeholder and a select. i need that when an option selected, the text of placeholder of input changes.

**i think that bootstrap.js binds it's objects when page is loaded and after document.ready, changes in those objects will not affect.**

my attempt:

```
$('select').on('change', function ()
{
    $('input').attr('placeholder',$(this).val())
});
```

that not work

Comment: Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/n6z0kqgz/

Comment: This work here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/vf9203hv/

Comment: Maybe delegate event, e.g: `$(document).on('change', 'select', function (){...});`

Comment: I don't think bootstrap does anything at all to selects or inputs with js, unless you're using a bootstrap dropdown, which isn't a select at all...

Comment: ohhhh! i used that input with `id='alert'` this was  my mistake. it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    $('input').attr('placeholder', $(this).val());
});
```

You should assign IDs or something other selector to the target `select` and target `input`. The code above will execute on every `input` any time any `select` is changed.

Comment: ohhhh! i used that input with `id='alert'` this was  my mistake. it's solved!